# Can someone please help me interpret this regression model

Tags: multiple-regression, interpretation

I want to understand predictors of wine spending. Below are the results of my model. I can see they are all significant predictors apart from marital status.

The question I have is how can I best understand the meaning of the b coefficient (Estimate)?

For example if I wanted to use the b coefficient of Age to understand how that affects spending on wine, how would I do that?

I've seen previously in an example that it's possible to increase sales on the basis of understanding how an increase in a predictor leads to an increase in sales. By that same principle, how can I use it to interpret these predictors based on the b coefficient. I hope my question makes sense.

[image: Model Screenshot]

Comment: Which predictors are continuous (numeric) and which are categorical?  For example, kidhome looks like its the number of kids. Is thst true?  And what are the units of MntWines?  This is a monetary value?

Comment: Assuming your outcome is dollars spent on wine, then the interpretation is as follows: the expected change in wine spending  associated with a 1 unit change in age is -$1.01. The coefficients of your model are the expected changes in y associated with a unit change in x.